# How would I make ionic segment swipeable when I slide the slider of the content

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a slider feature whenever a user slides the page in ionic application. To elaborate, when I swipe the slider the segment button does highlights but the remaining segment buttons are hidden where I have to swipe the slider manually. Is there any way to make the whole segment slide as when I swipe the content?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by using angular animation and translating the segment component horizontally. How you are going to use animation depends upon you.

Comment: I am finding the solution to do that. I also try to do it with both `ion-slides` and `swiper`, but it doesn't work as I wish the layout to be. How did you solve this issue back then. Thanks.